# When a row in a table is relying on another tables information, do you need to add those rows into that same table as a foreign key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am currently creating a database for my school project based on this information:

[image: ERD of database]

If you look at the ERD of the pokemon database I posted, on the `pokemonFight` table, it includes `pokemonFightExpPoint`. Now after talking to someone in my class, we figured out there's no constraint needed (other than the check constraint). But also, the `pokemonId` , `battleId`, and `battleLocationId` are foreign keys from the other tables.

It was noted in my assignment that

> Pokémon can play any battles at any battle locations. In other words, the battle experience points are functionally
> dependent on Pokémon, battle, and battle location.

I am just wondering if in order to add the PokemonFightExpoint column, you NEED to add `pokemonId`, `battleId`, and `battlelocationId`s to this table? Is it somehow getting data from these foreign keys that were added?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thats when joins come in. You join all 3 tables together to pull the information from the other tables related by foreign key - this is a fundamental basic of relational databases. That said a foreign key is not required to join 2 tables, what it does do is maintain the integrity of those tables i.e. when you define a foreign key relationship you can't put a value in that column unless the record it relates to exists. However this is all too much for an answer here, you need to go find a join tutorial.

Comment: @DaleK thanks for helping me tonight, I've been practicing joins to make queries lately. I felt pretty good until I had to put it all together finally. 

I think I understand enough about how to join tables together to get a query of the data you want, but when it comes to actually creating the pokemonFight table, I'm still kind of confused. Since the other tables include pokemonId, battleId, and battleLocationId, wouldn't they exist there? Or do these foreign keys have to be added to the same table (pokemonFight table) in order to put a value in pokemonFightExpPoint?

Comment: In fact now I realise I am confused, the `pokemonFight` table as shown **already** has the `pokemonId`, `battleId`, and `battlelocationId` columns - which yes you do need to store in order to know the full details of the fight.

Comment: Thank you!! I get it now. :D I was definitely over thinking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add `PokemonFightExpoint` you need not to add `pokemonId`, `battleId` or `battlelocationId` to the table.

However to know at which location what kind of battle happened you need to add `battlelocationId` and `battleId` to this table. And `pokemonId` is refereeing the pokemon who fought the battle.

You are not going to get any data from those foreign keys. As @Dale k mentioned in comment foreign key will force the data integrity. It will prevent you from adding any `pokemonId`, `battleId` or `battlelocationId` to the table which is not available in respective tables.

You are doing great in designing. Best wishes.